Wrote a PINN to try to simulate 1-D heat transfer through a medium with constant diffusivity. The model doesn't even learn the boundary conditions!

I divide my training into 2 parts. a) Training on the boundary conditions within the domain. b) Training on the pde_loss.
The problem goes something like this: Both the ends of a 1 dimensional thermally conducting rod are submerged in a sink of temperature 0 units(arbitrary to avoid running into thermodynamic issues). On the right is the analytical solution to the heat equation obtained by solving using the same boundary conditions. But on the left is the solution the PINN comes up with. The difference is night and day.
My architecture is simple but I don't know what more I can do for it to learn better. Maybe increase the number of samples I am training on? Currently training on 1000 data points each consisting of 1 timestep value and a spatial coordinate value. Also keep in mind I train it like 4 times, 1 for each boundary condition and then on the pde loss.
Here's the code if you'd like to assess:
# gonna write a PINN to solve some random pde; maybe the heat equation.
# Let's introduce some boundary conditions picked up from a problem in my textbook:
'''
1. u(0, t) = 0
2. u(1, t) = 0
3. u(x, 0) = sin(pi*x)
'''

# The approach is to define a new loss function that will evaluate the loss in the predictions 
# when the boundary conditions are met and then update the parameters accordingly.

import math
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

alpha = 0.03
epochs = 1000

class PINN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, output_size):
        super(PINN, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.output_size = output_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size

        self.linear1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
        self.tanh = nn.Tanh()
        self.linear2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, hidden_size)
        self.linear3 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, output_size)
        self.output_layer = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 1)

    def forward(self, x, t):
        x = torch.concat([x, t], dim=1)
        out = self.linear1(x)
        out = self.tanh(out)
        out = self.linear2(out)
        out = self.tanh(out)
        out = self.linear3(out)
        return out
    

def pinn_loss(model, alpha, x, t):
    x.requires_grad = True
    t.requires_grad = True
    u = model(x, t)
    u_t = torch.autograd.grad(u, t, create_graph=True, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(t_colloc))[0]
    u_x = torch.autograd.grad(u, x, create_graph=True, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(x_colloc))[0]
    u_xx = torch.autograd.grad(u_x, x, create_graph=True, grad_outputs=torch.ones_like(x_colloc))[0]

    physics_loss = u_t - (alpha)*u_xx # The wave equation modified such that the ideal outuput would be 0
    physics_loss = torch.mean(physics_loss**2)
    return physics_loss

def bc_training(model, optimizer, num_epochs):
    # Trains for the first BC
    zero_space = torch.zeros((1000, 1), requires_grad=True)
    time = torch.rand((1000, 1), requires_grad=True)
    print("Training on BCs..........")
    BC_training_compact(model, optimizer, zero_space, time, num_epochs, 1)

    final_coords = torch.ones((1000, 1), requires_grad=True)
    time = torch.rand((1000, 1), requires_grad=True)
    BC_training_compact(model, optimizer, final_coords, time, num_epochs, 2)

    space_coords = torch.rand((1000, 1), requires_grad=True)
    time = torch.zeros((1000, 1), requires_grad=True)
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        loss = BC3_loss(model, space_coords, time)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        print(f"BC: 3, epoch: {epoch}, BC_loss: {loss.item()}")


def BC_training_compact(model, optimizer, x, t, num_epochs, BC):
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        u = model(x, t)
        loss = torch.mean(torch.square(u))
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        print(f"BC: {BC}, epoch: {epoch}, BC_loss: {loss.item()}")

def BC3_loss(model, x, t):
    u = model(x, t)
    correct_vals = torch.sin(math.pi * x)
    loss = torch.mean((correct_vals - u)**2)
    return loss

def check_parameters(model):
    # to verify that training did produce changes in the parameters.
    params = {}
    for name, param in model.named_parameters():
        params[name] = param.clone().detach()
    return params

        
model = PINN(2, 25, 1)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-4)

initial_params = check_parameters(model)

def analytical_solution(x, t, alpha):
    return torch.exp(-alpha * (torch.pi ** 2) * t) * torch.sin(torch.pi * x)


# Training on BCs first
bc_training(model, optimizer, num_epochs=1000)

final_params = check_parameters(model)


# Generating random data -- Have no idea if any of these points will actually satisfy this equation or nah but I'll iterate.
x = torch.rand(20) * (1 - 0) + 0
t = torch.rand(20) * (1 - 0) + 0
X, T = torch.meshgrid(x, t)
x_colloc = torch.tensor(X.flatten(), dtype=torch.float32).view(-1, 1)
t_colloc = torch.tensor(T.flatten(), dtype=torch.float32).view(-1, 1)

print("x_colloc shape: ", x_colloc.shape)
print("t_colloc shape: ", t_colloc.shape)


# Training on the pde loss
for epoch in range(epochs):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss = pinn_loss(model, alpha, x_colloc, t_colloc) # calcualtes physics loss per epoch
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    print(f"epoch: {epoch}, loss: {loss.item()}")

# Plot results
x_plot = torch.linspace(0, 1, 500).view(-1, 1)
t_plot = torch.linspace(0, 1, 500).view(-1, 1)
X_plot, T_plot = torch.meshgrid(x_plot.view(-1), t_plot.view(-1))

# Flatten the grid for model input
x_flat = X_plot.flatten().view(-1, 1)
t_flat = T_plot.flatten().view(-1, 1)

# Get model predictions
u_pred = model(x_flat, t_flat).detach().numpy()
U_plot = u_pred.reshape(500, 500)

# Get analytical solution
u_analytic = analytical_solution(X_plot, T_plot, alpha=alpha).numpy()

# Plotting
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))

# PINN Solution
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121, projection='3d')
ax1.plot_surface(X_plot.numpy(), T_plot.numpy(), U_plot, cmap='viridis')
ax1.set_xlabel('x')
ax1.set_ylabel('t')
ax1.set_zlabel('u')
ax1.set_title('PINN Solution')

# Analytical Solution
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')
ax2.plot_surface(X_plot.numpy(), T_plot.numpy(), u_analytic, cmap='viridis')
ax2.set_xlabel('x')
ax2.set_ylabel('t')
ax2.set_zlabel('u')
ax2.set_title('Analytical Solution')

plt.show()

I suspect the issue is in the way I am training the model on the boundary conditions because I think the model should at the very least learn the function's behaviour at the boundaries since I trained on those conditions for over a thousand times!! Maybe I need to define a different loss?
If you have any ideas or can spot any stupid mistakes I've made, please reply below and let me know. Thank you so much for reading thus far!
